# Application updater code returns with 404 not found

Tags: vb.net, .htaccess, httpwebrequest

Since I'm making a program, I wanted to add an application updater to it. I searched here (usually I find my answers here from other topics) but this one returned with none, just like my problem. :D

I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub worker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles worker1.DoWork
   Try
      Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://nighthawk1037.comze.com/apps/gmailbomber/currentversion.txt")
      Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
      Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
      Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
      Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion

      If newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then
         MessageBox.Show("You have the current version", "Update Check")
      Else
         MessageBox.Show("A Newer version is available! Gmail Email Bomber will attempt to download and run the new update!", "Update Check")
         My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(New Uri("http://nighthawk1037.comze.com/apps/gmailbomber/update/gmail_email_bomberv1-beta2.exe"), "C:\Program Files\gmailbomber\gmail_email_bomberv1-beta2.exe", "", "", True, 60000, True, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
         Process.Start("C:\Program Files\gmailbomber\gmail_email_bomberv1-beta2.exe")
         Me.Close()
      End If

    Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

To make my VB.Net program check my website for the currentversion.txt and if it's a new one it would download the latest version. Usually this works when I try it offline (wamp server)
But for some reason the `ex.message` returns with a `The remote server returned an error: (404 Not found).` Message. Which of course means that the directory/file is not on the remote server. But I've confirmed about 10 times and everything is on my website, links are correct and everything is supposed to work correctly, but for some reason I get that error.
Is it because of file permissions?

Note: I have an `.htaccess` on `nighthawk1037.comze.com/apps` where it redirects to a `index.php` file in the same directory and that redirects to the home page, but I removed that and still got the error, now the only thing my `.htaccess` has is `IndexIgnore` so people wouldn't be able to check the files.

Comment: Any ideas what causes it?

Comment: Keep in mind that the Program Files folder is read-only when running as a standard user (or with UAC enabled). Download to the temp folder.

Comment: If you think the problem might be with the .htaccess file, remove it and check again. Or try putting the file in a different directory and see if it works.

Comment: It downloads it to where the program is installed in c:\program files\gmailbomber\gmail_email_bomberv0.2.exe
And nope, deleting the .htaccess isn't working. :/

Comment: Extremely wierd! Check this out:-> http://nighthawk1037.comze.com/apps/
That's the apps directory, completely empty, though when i ftp uploaded it, the directory content is there.. 
Here's the screen of the ftp: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/appsid.png/

Comment: Try chmodding the whole directory to 777. -Vlad

Comment: @IrfanDahir Remarks like 'Y U no HELP ME?' are highly unlikely to persuade anybody to help.   Text-speak is never acceptable here and is likely to get edited on sight. 
The fact that there have been edits on your question perhaps suggests your original question was wanting.  Similarly lines like 'I need an answer fast' suggest to readers that you're out of your depth and need them to do your work on your behalf - which is not what SO is about.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I was new to stackoverflow at that time. Didn't know what the editing was about. Anyway, how do I close this question? As I'm not learning vb anymore.